# MavLink ArduPilot - Can’t parse PARAM_VALUE request

Tags: buffer, mavlink

My friend and I are trying to communicate with a drone (APM 2.8 flight controller - ArduCopter V3.2.1 (36b405fb)) with **MavLink**. After several hours, we managed to handle messages and make ByteBuffers a little more meaningful but we're stuck on parsing one response that seems to didn’t fit with the documentation.

When performing a **PARAM_REQUEST_LIST request**, the APM sends back (a lot of) **PARAM_VALUE (#22)** responses, but the format of what we're receiving is really not what we’ve expected

The payload

```
<Buffer cd cc 4c 3f 32 01 36 00 45 4b 46 5f 43 48 45 43 4b 5f 54 48 52 45 53 48 09>
```

The expected object [(doc)](https://mavlink.io/en/messages/common.html#PARAM_VALUE)

```
PARAM_VALUE
{
    param_id    char[16]
    param_value float
    param_type  uint8_t
    param_count uint16_t
    param_index uint16_t
}
```

So param_id =  cd cc 4c 3f 32 01 36 00 45 4b 46 5f 43 48 45 43 = ÍÌL?2(soh)6(nul)EKF_CHEC

Although the 8 last characters are OK, it seems that the first 8 characters are absolutely everything but not the beginning of a char[16] - by the way the 8th is always (nul) … And it’s the same for a param_count = 17747 when param_index = 18441 (?!), the different param_count values in every response, or param_type=82 when this value must be 0 < x <= 10 [(doc)](https://mavlink.io/en/messages/common.html#MAV_PARAM_TYPE)

We already managed to parse other requests without any problem so we thought we’d understood the way MavLink works but I'm doubting right now … **Did we miss something obvious ? Or is there a problem with the drone ?**

Answer (score 0):

For those who encountered the same problem, [this page](https://mavlink.io/en/guide/serialization.html#field_reordering) is the answer. According to this, my object looks more like that when reordered

```
PARAM_VALUE
{
    param_value float
    param_count uint16_t
    param_index uint16_t
    param_id    char[16]
    param_type  uint8_t
}
```

So param_id = 45 4b 46 5f 43 48 45 43 4b 5f 54 48 52 45 53 48 = EKF_CHECK_THRESH